Have Homebrew ask for the admin password instead of the password of the current user when installing a cask
When I install a Homebrew cask, I need to enter the password of the current user at the end of the process to actually install the applicaiton.
Is there a way to change Homebrew so it asks for the password of an admin user instead?

How do you run brew to ask for any password? Usually it doesn‘t need one. Is this specifically about the password asked during the installation of a cask?

No. Whenever I run brew install --cask "some_program" , I am prompted for the user's password. I'd like to be prompted for the Admin password on my Mac for increased  security.

Are you asked immediately (no brew output yet), or during an installation (brew has already printed some progress information)?

During installation. Brew printed all progress info. It's the last thing.

Homebrew does not recommend installing packages using sudo commands, because there is an inherent risk that one of the packages you are installing could exit macOS' sandbox and modify the system. So Homebrew does not recommend installing packages with admin passwords (aka sudo). See their FAQ: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad

@AVelj with the explanations the OP gave, I assume they are not running brew with sudo but rather need to enter the password to install the application within a cask to /Applications or similar.

@MC23 I am not sure how this is increased security. The process is using sudo which logs who did the change. Admin user is often a shared user or if not it does not add anything.

If your password passes the check you are an admin already. Non-admin users cannot pass the check. If you want to use what you claim is the 'admin' password, then you would install brew packages as root. As others have already pointed out, and is also specifically mentioned in the brew docs, this is definitely not recommended. Thought root's password can be set, it is not done so in a standard macOS install specifically to avoid any brute-force or other socially engineered attack. Doing so doesn't increase security in any way, rather it leaves your machine open to more attack vectors.

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/102367 The user account named ”root” is a superuser with read and write privileges to more areas of the system, including files in other macOS user accounts. The root user is disabled by default, and it's not intended for routine use. Its privileges allow changes to files that are required by your Mac, and to undo those changes you might need to reinstall macOS. 

So, to clarify, my settings as an Admin user prevent any downloads onto my Mac by a standard user without the Admin password being entered. By installing Homebrew (with initial Admin permission), this safeguard can now be circumvented, with any cask now able to be downloaded by any Standard user?

Sounds like you need to reword your question to ask how to prevent use of brew by a non-admin user.

After installing brew with the default command as an admin or another sudoer, you shouldn't be able to install anything as another less privileged user, because you have no write permissions to important brew folders. (checked in macOS 12). Which mods have been applied by you?

Not sure what you mean by mods. I installed homebrew as a Standard user, which required the Admin password to be entered upon installation. After that, every brew install requires the Standard user password. I'm on macOs 14.5.

Do cask installations complete successful if you enter the password of the current user when asked?

Yes they do, and I want to know if there's any way to change that. Would it help if I uninstall homebrew and re-installed from inside the actual Admin user account?

Well, yes, if you install it as an admin user, you will to run all installs/updates as that user. Still don‘t see how this would improve security or anything.

With mods I meant modifications of file system permissions (/opt/homebrew/... or /usr/local/... depending on your cpu) or up-/downgrading your standard user temporarily.
